# Network interface for VPN connection explanation

Tags: vpn, ifconfig

I'd like to know exactly what is happening when I create a connection with my company's VPN.

When I connect (using OpenVPN), I see the following network interface by using `ifconfig`:

```
utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.18 --> 10.8.0.17 netmask 0xffffffff
```

This looks different from other network interfaces in that it has two IP addresses separated by "-->".

#### Question(s)

Which is those two numbers is my actual IP address? What is the other one, then? How can the netmask be `0xffffffff`? Seems to not leave any address space to identify individual hosts on the network.

I know this is kind of multiple questions, but they all seem very closely related so I figured I'd ask them all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a **point-to-point** interface, also called a tunnel or a peer-to-peer interface. It doesn't behave like "shared medium" interfaces such as Wi-Fi or Ethernet, which connect you to multiple devices through use of layer-2 MAC addresses. Instead, it behaves like a cable that just has hosts on both ends.

(Indeed originally such interfaces *meant* a serial link cable running PPP or similar protocol. But for `tun*` and `utun*` interfaces, the "other end" is the VPN program.)

There are no layer-2 headers, no MAC addresses, and no ARP on a point-to-point interface, because everything sent through it reaches the same destination (the "peer" host).

> Seems to not leave any address space to identify individual hosts on the network.

It doesn't actually *have* a "subnet mask" so to speak; it's just two single addresses. This is a common configuration for point-to-point links, although not exclusive to them.

With "normal" interfaces, configuring an address with subnet mask like `192.168.1.3/24` on eth0 is really just shorthand for saying "My address is `192.168.1.3` and I also have an on-link route `192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0`". The on-link route is derived from combining the address & subnet mask.

With point-to-point interfaces, it's actually the same idea. Your example means "My address is `10.8.0.18` and I also have an on-link route `10.8.0.17/32 dev utun3`." In this case the autogenerated route is a /32, indicating only one host – the "peer".

*(Note: My examples use Linux iproute2-style syntax.)*

So in the end, the difference between these two configuration styles is just that automatic route.

In fact, in some other operating systems (e.g. Linux) *any* interface can use either subnet-style or PtP-style configuration. Often VPNs and other point-to-point tunnels have a traditional subnet mask, because the autogenerated route makes a lot of sense for them (even if there's no actual MAC subnet). And in rare cases, normal Ethernet interfaces might use PtP-style `X --> Y` configuration because they're on a weird network.

---

By the way, another configuration you might see on point-to-point interfaces is /31, which is a subnet with only two addresses total and *both* are host addresses – /31 prefixes are actually exempt from the usual "netid and broadcast are reserved" rule (though not all operating systems have been updated to know this).

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation!

Comment: Good job, have a cookie!

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! How does the route table get updated for this type of /32 link? Sometimes the VPN will be the default route and sometimes there will be a list of valid routes to add.

Comment: @DanielK: It's mostly the same; you still have a direct route to your gateway, so when the VPN client adds a default route it might look like `0.0.0.0/0 via 10.8.0.17`. (For PtP interfaces it might also be `0.0.0.0/0 dev utun0`, as routes via tun/utun don't need a gateway address, but important to note that this comes from the PtP interfaces themselves lacking a layer-2, and _not_ from their usage of /32 address configuration.)

Comment: How is the other end is the VPN program? Can you bind a tunnel interface to a process?

Comment: That is *literally the purpose* of tun interfaces.

Comment: @D.Jones - explains a bit more on TUN - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82673/what-is-the-tun-network-interface-for